# InvalidArgumentError: Input to reshape is a tensor with 178802 values, but the requested shape has 89401

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm running into another invalid argument error and not really sure what the reason is this time.

I created a TFRecord with images (mixed extensions as far I know) of shape [299,299].

I'm trying to load the images in batches, but I'm running into this error:

```
'InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 178802 values, but the requested shape has 89401
     [[Node: Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](DecodeRaw, Reshape/shape)]]
```

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

IMAGE_DIR =r'C:\Users\Moondra\Desktop\TF_FISH_PROJECT\FINAL_FISHES'

data_path = r'E:\TFRECORDS\normal_fish_conversion_2.tfrecords'  

with tf.Session() as sess:
    feature = {'train/image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
               'train/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
               'rows':  tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                'columns':  tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}

    # Create a list of filenames and pass it to a queue
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([data_path], num_epochs=1000)

    # Define a reader and read the next record
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

    # Decode the record read by the reader
    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feature)

    # Convert the image data from string back to the numbers
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['train/image'], tf.float32)

    # Cast label data into int32
    label = tf.cast(features['train/label'], tf.int32)

    # Reshape image data into the original shape
    image = tf.reshape(image, [299, 299])
    print(image.shape) #shape is printing out correctly


    # Creates batches by randomly shuffling tensors
    #images, labels = tf.train.shuffle_batch([image, label], batch_size=50, capacity=10000, num_threads=3, min_after_dequeue=2000)
    init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(init_op)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for batch_index in range(5):
            img  = sess.run([image])
            img = img.astype(np.uint8)
            print(img.shape)





    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()
```

I'm not really sure how to debug this..

The first print statement( reshaped_image.shape) is printing out a
(299,299) shape, so not sure what the problem is.

Thank you.

Comment: Reshape will just change the ratio along a tensor dimensions. It seems your raw images do not fit the target matrix. How about scaling the images before the reshape?

Comment: What you mean by scaling? As for the raw images, I resized them to [299,299] explicitly before writing them to TFrecords. So shouldn't my raw images have 299x299 pixels? Thank you.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure. If images are, say, FullHD, reshape to the target size won't work. So the problem is elsewhere. Looking at it. No problem with encoding? Like decoding raw, where the data is JPEG? The Inception tutorial shows an example with JPEG images.

Comment: Hard for me to tell more without having a look at the data. It may be that an image in is not the right size. The code looks fine. Perhaps you could print the length of each `decode_raw` and see when the 178802 comes up, which is surprisingly 2 x 299 x 299.

Comment: @EricPlaton   I didn't run into any problems when encoding to string-bytes (before writing to TFRecords). However, I think my images are using different extensions (besides jpegs). I wonder if that is causing a problem.  I will try printing out `decode_raw` length and see if the 178802 is an outlier. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @EricPlaton So you are right;  There is def an image of shape 178802. I can't seem to run a batch of images as I'm getting a different error: 
`ValueError: All shapes must be fully defined: [TensorShape([Dimension(None)]), TensorShape([])`. So I can't see if the other images have a similar problem.

Comment: @EricPlaton So I was able to run a bunch of images and print out their length -- all of them have 178802. Which is baffling as I rewrote to my TFRecords and printed the size of each image before converting it to string-bytes -- all of them are (299x299)

Comment: Would there be something like two channels per image? This may be a weird idea, but not sure about your data.

Comment: Just a guess but maybe your images are `tf.float64`, and you're splitting each pixel by casting to `tf.float32`?

Comment: @Stephen I see. This makes sense. I will test this out later tonight. If this doesn't work, I will just put it on hold, and slowly debug step by step.

Answer (score 3):

What I needed to do is decoding the image to JPEG, converting it to float, expanding its dimensions and then resizing it using bilinear interpolation like this:

```
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(features['train/image'], channels=3)
image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)
image = tf.image.resize_bilinear(image, [299, 299], align_corners=False)
```

NOTE:

- Your images should be already stored in JPEG format (when creating the TFRecords).
- You can instead set the `channels` to 1 if your images are grayscale or save the number of channels for every image in your TFRecords and get it from there dynamically (different for every image).